# Unable to get response from an ajax api call getting cors error ,working fine in post man. I have added the cors headers in request

Tags: javascript, ajax

I am using this code:-

```
  var saveData=$.ajax({
                            url: "api",
                            headers: {
                                "Access-Control-Allow-Origin":"*",
                                "Access-Control-Request-Headers": "x-requested-with",
                                 "Access-Control-Allow-Methods": "GET, POST, PATCH, PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS",
                                 "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, Content-Type, X-Auth-Token",
                                 "Accept":"application/json"
                                    },
                    type: 'POST',
                         dataType: 'application/octet-stream',
    contentType: 'image/jpeg',
    processData: false,
    data: binaryData,
    success: function (data) {
      alert(data);
    },
    error: function(){
      alert("Cannot get data");
    }
});
```

But I am getting this:-
Access to XMLHttpRequest at 'api/bintest1.jpeg' from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.

But it is working fine in postman:-
[image]

[image]

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Why does my JavaScript code get a "No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource" error when Postman does not?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20035101/why-does-my-javascript-code-get-a-no-access-control-allow-origin-header-is-pr)

Comment: But I have given the headers

Comment: Please could you help me out .Thanks in advance.I am not getting solution and I am stuck

Comment: @gaurabk These headers are response headers. There is no use in sending them as request headers. The changes should be made on server to send these response headers.

Comment: But i have allowed CORS in api gateway @nithin

Comment: @gourabk You have enabled CORS only for `GET` requests.